# Angular Timer When User Stops Clicking

Tags: angularjs

I have this application with a bunch of check boxes. Checking/un-checking these boxes will fire an `$http.post()` to the server. I want it to now fire 1 post as soon as the user is done clicking, but I'm not sure how to set up my `$timeout`.

I have a plunker set up here: https://plnkr.co/edit/QJRc9uMxJA17eFszyexO

What this currently does is that when the user checks a checkbox, a single alert is fired after 1 sec. (Im using the alert to simulate the `$http.post()`.

Is there a way that I can reset that `$timeout` when the user clicks on a new check box? So if I click on 5 checkboxes continuously, it will fire 1 alert rather than 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$timeout()` returns a promise (you can call `.then()` on it, but that's another story). Also there is `$timeout.cancel(promise)` to cancel a pending timeout. So modify your code as:

```
app.controller('IndexController', function($scope, $timeout) {

  var prevTimeout;

  $scope.onClick = function() {
    if( prevTimeout ) {
      $timeout.cancel(prevTimeout);
    }
    prevTimeout = $timeout(function() {
      prevTimeout = null;
      alert('some http post called.');
    }, 1000);
  };

  $scope.model = new Array(5);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is debounce functionality. If you are using lodasd check https://lodash.com/docs#debounce